# get another JSON object properties by given one

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON objects like this one:

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "fullname": "Kevin Johnson",
    "usernames": ["kevin123", "kevinj", "kjohnson"]
}
```

Now if I know the person's ID, I want to get their usernames and full name from JSON. Also, if I know one of the person's usernames, I want to get their ID and full name. How do I get the necessary information?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: If you have an array of such objects, you can look at `Array.prototype.find()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: where's your other data, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Add the code you tried.

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.find()` for both of the scenario.

**Get fullname and usernames by id**

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "id": 12345,
    "fullname": "Kevin Johnson",
    "usernames": ["kevin123", "kevinj", "kjohnson"]
  },
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "fullname": "Mark Johnson",
    "usernames": ["Mark123", "Markj", "12Mark"]
  }
];

var id = 123456;
var resObj = obj.find(item => item.id === id);
if(resObj){
  console.log('Full name ', resObj.fullname);
  console.log('usernames ', resObj.usernames);
} else {
  console.log('No user found!');
}
```

**Get id and fullname from username**

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "id": 12345,
    "fullname": "Kevin Johnson",
    "usernames": ["kevin123", "kevinj", "kjohnson"]
  },
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "fullname": "Mark Johnson",
    "usernames": ["Mark123", "Markj", "12Mark"]
  }
];

var username = 'kevinj';
var resObj = obj.find(item => item.usernames.includes(username));
if(resObj){
  console.log('Full name ', resObj.fullname);
  console.log('id ', resObj.id);
} else {
  console.log('No user found!');
}
```

Comment: Important to note that internet explorer does not have find, so a polyfill will be required if IE needs to be supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @JonMac1374 there has always been exceptions in IE. Specially with ES6.

Answer (score 3):

To find fullname and usernames against a given id:

```
var data = JSON.parse(your_json_string_here);
var person = data.find( x => x.id == **some_user_id**);
var fullName = person.fullname;
var usernames = person.usernames;
```

To find id and fullname from username:

```
var person = data.find( x => x.usernames.indexOf(**some_user_name**) > 0 );
```